# How to include multiple conditions in one equivalence statement?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I'm trying to trigger a condition if a variable meets one of two values. I'm aware I can express this as:

```
if x == 5 || x == 6
    execute code...
end
```

But I was wondering if there was something a bit more elegant in case `x` has a long name. Something like:

```
if x == {5, 6}
    execute code...
end
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed there is a general approach. You can use the [`any`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function to test if `x` is equal to any of the elements of the array:

```
if any(x == [5, 6])
    % execute code
end
```

This works for numerical arrays. If you’re dealing with cell arrays, you can use  [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) (thanks @ nilZ0r!)

```
choices = {'foo', 'bar', 'hello'};
x = 'hello';

if ismember(x, choices)
    % execute code
end
```

`ismember` works for both numerical and cell arrays (thanks @TasosPapastylianou).

Comment: If you switch the order of the input to `ismember()` you can skip the `any` before it ( `ismember(x, choices)` instead of `any(ismember(choices, x))`

Comment: actually, you can use `ismember` for your top case too. It's nicer and clearer. I was going to post that as an answer when I saw part 2 here :)

Comment: Thanks @nilZ0r and @TasosPapastylianou! It’s a matter of style, but I think `any` is more idomatic in Matlab for numerical arrays.

Answer (score 3):

A [**`switch-case`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) environment would be an elegant choice:

```
switch x
    case {5,6}
        x.^2
    case {7,8}
        x.^4
    otherwise
        x.^3
end
```

works for strings as well:

```
switch x
    case {'foo','bar'}
        disp(x)
    otherwise
        disp('fail.')
end
```

Comment: Nice! Didn’t know about that use of `switch-case`. +1